# QtScript and threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtscript

I want to run several concurrent jobs from QtScript script:

```
function job1() { ... }
function job2() { ... }

runConcurrentJobs(job1, job2)
```

The jobs a essentially sequences of remote procedure calls (ZeroC Ice), which need to synchronize at several points.

The Qt 4.8.0 documentation says nothing about `QScriptEngine` thread-safety.  My questions:

1. Is it safe to use single `QScriptEngine` to exectute QtScript functions from multiple thread concurrently?
2. What approach would you recommend to accomplish the task?

**Notes:**

1. Scripts are edited not by programmers but also by electric engineers and I want to keep the script as simple and clean as possible.

Comment: What type of remote procedure call are you using? AJAX? D-Bus?

Answer (score 1):

`QScriptEngine` is documented as "reentrant", meaning, essentially, you can use it multi-threaded, but only one `QScriptEngine` per thread.

Now, if functions `job1()` and `job2()` can be run concurrently at all, in principle, it should be possible to separate them into two distinct `QScriptEngine`s (easy, if neither the functions use local variables, only, more difficult, if globals are involved).

1. Implement `runConcurrentJobs()` as a `Q_INVOKABLE` function (or slot) in C++.
2. In there, do something like

   ```
      void runConcurrently (const QString &functionname1, QString &functionname2) {
          MyScriptThread thread1 (functionname1);
          MyScriptThread thread2 (functionname2);
          thread1.start();
          thread2.start();
          thread1.wait ();
          thread2.wait ();
          // optionally fetch return values from the threads and return them
      }
   ```
3. Where MyScriptThread is derived from QThread and implements QThread::run() roughly like this:

   ```
      void MyScriptThread::run () {
            QScriptEngine engine;
            engine.evaluate (common_script_code);
            result = engine.evaluate (the_threads_function);
            // the_threads_function passed as a QScriptProgram or QString
      }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. In general, if documentation says nothing about threading, it is not thread safe.
2. I would rewrite to use asynchronous requests. Just kick them both off, then wait for them both.

Comment: Using async API is not a solution: scripts are edited not by programmers but also by electric engineers and I want to keep the script as simple and clean as possible. I do not think that interleaved async calls can called a clean code.  I'll try to write a combinator library to simulate the look-and-feel I want.

Comment: Easiest solution is to teach the engineers to write an async call.